# C# playing sound from one speaker at a time

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am trying to play sound from one speaker/earphone at a time. So I  zero out the values for one side. but it is not working. 
in a wav file the even values play from the right speaker/ hearphone and the old from the left right ?
so why it is not working

here is my code:

```
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount)
    {
        if (position == 0 && onetimeflag == false)
        {
            n2 = 0;
            onetimeflag = true;
        }
        if (n2 >= Bufferlength && stopflag == false)
        {
            Dispose();
            return 0;
        }

        float temp1;
        for (int i = 0; i < (sampleCount / 4); i++)
        {
            if (Frequency_switch == true)
            {
                temp1 = (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin(Math.PI * Frequency * n2 / 44100D));
                Frequency_switch = false;
            }
            else
            {

                temp1 = (float)(Amplitude2 * Math.Sin((Math.PI * Frequency2 * n2) / 44100D));
                Frequency_switch = true;
            }
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(temp1);
            buffer[i * 4 + 0] = bytes[0];
            buffer[i * 4 + 1] = bytes[1];
            buffer[i * 4 + 2] = bytes[2];
            buffer[i * 4 + 3] = bytes[3];

            tempSample++;
            n2++;
        }
        return sampleCount;}} }
```

I am using the NAudio library

here is how I play the sound:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Play(1, 240, 0);
    }
    binaural_beats BBeats;
    WaveOut waveout;
    void Play(double Amp, double Left, double Right)
    {
        BBeats = new binaural_beats();
        BBeats.Amplitude = Amp;
        BBeats.Amplitude2 = Amp;
        BBeats.Frequency = Left;
        BBeats.Frequency2 = Right;

        BBeats.Bufferlength = 44100 * 2 * 3;// will play for 3 sec

        waveout = new WaveOut();
        WaveChannel32 temp = new WaveChannel32(BBeats);
        temp.PadWithZeroes = false;

        waveout.Init(temp);
        waveout.Play();

    }
```

Comment: I cannot see where do you fill second channel with zeros. You need to write first 4 bytes with sample data, then another 4 bytes with zeros.

Comment: there is a switch...  and i set the  Amplitude2 to 0

Comment: Oh I see... Can you just try to fill second channel with zeros? For testing purposes. Should that 'n2++' be called for each two samples, not for just one?

Comment: for each sample

Comment: I do fill up one channel with 0..

Comment: so it is even indexes are one channel and odd indexes are another channel right ?

Comment: If you have stereo 32-bit float format, you have something like this: `LLLLRRRRLLLLRRRR`... (if I remember it good). LLLL = 4 bytes = 1 sample for left channel. Can you say what you hear in both channels? More code would be good, maybe problem is in a different place.

Comment: I hear the same sound coming out of both ear phones

Comment: Post entire code for `BBeats` so I will be able to run it on my machine.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0vms9d9jjq4vhbn/AACn9ym-OJKLhitFbFQJ1pqya?dl=0

Comment: that is the link to the fully code

Comment: for me, everything sounds fine. It is hard to tell from what direction low frequencies come (using speakers). Try higher frequencies and use headphones. `Play (1, 10000, 300);` looks fine for testing purposes.

Comment: when i put a 0 for the left or the right, it should not play any sound from that side, but it does

Comment: I do the same and I don't here anything. Maybe you have some kind of post processing enabled in your sound card?

Comment: really ??? WTF?? what is post processing ?? and how do i turn it off ?

Comment: post processing - some special effects that your sound card can do, e.g. 'echo'. You can manage these effects with software provided by your sound card manufacturer. Did you tried to listen it on headphones?

Comment: yes!! I have tried many different headphones!!! I cant believe it is working for you but not me... this is so weird

Comment: so you only hear sound out of one ear bug? I hear sound out of both.. and again I have tried like 3 different head phone.

Comment: my computer has a Realtek High Definition Audio device.

Comment: open Realtek HD audio manager, and try to disable some effects if enabled (speaker visualization for example)

Comment: I do not see any effects on. If I save the waveform to the file,  and play it on audacity, and I turn the pan does all the right to the right or all the way to the left , it will work right . but how do i do that in my program ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131758/discussion-between-apocalypse-and-brandon).